# How to upload the scraped data from a website into excel and database at once?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Hi I am scraping the teacher jobs from this website https://www.indeed.co.in/?r=us now I want to upload them to excel and database at once how is it possible can anyone help me 
I want to get like the headers title, company, salary and the data
My scrap.py code for scraping is :

```
import selenium.webdriver

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://www.indeed.co.in/?r=us'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"mypython/bin/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver")


driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text-input-what"]').send_keys("teacher")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="whatWhereFormId"]/div[3]/button').click()

# scrape data
data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "resultsCol")))
result_set = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "jobsearch-SerpJobCard")))

for result in result_set:
    data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "resultsCol")))
    result_set = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "jobsearch-SerpJobCard")))
    for result in result_set:

        title = result.find_element_by_class_name("title").text
        print(title)

        school = result.find_element_by_class_name("company").text
        print(school)

        try:
            salary = result.find_element_by_class_name("salary").text
            print(salary)
        except:
            pass
            print("--------")
    # move to next page
    next_page = result.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='pn']")[-1]
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i have made a few modifications to your code and below generates a csv with 200+ records from all the pages.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Mar  5 15:12:04 2020

@author: prakh
"""

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def smallest(a, y, z):
    M = a
    if y < M:
        M = y    
    if z < M:
        M = z
        if y < z:
            M = y
    return M
url = 'https://www.indeed.co.in/?r=us'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/prakh/Documents/PythonScripts/chromedriver.exe') 
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text-input-what"]').send_keys("teacher")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="whatWhereFormId"]/div[3]/button').click()

# scrape data
data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "resultsCol")))
result_set = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "jobsearch-SerpJobCard")))

Resultfile = open("teacherr_jobs.csv",'a',encoding='utf-8',newline='')
head = csv.writer(Resultfile)
head.writerow(["Title","School","Salary"])
Resultfile.close() 
titles = []
company = []
salaries = []
resultlist = []
Resultfile = open("teacherr_jobs.csv",'a',encoding='utf-8',newline='')
wr = csv.writer(Resultfile) 
for result in result_set:
    data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "resultsCol")))
    result_set = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "jobsearch-SerpJobCard")))
    for result in result_set:

        titles.append(result.find_element_by_class_name("title").text)
#        print(title)

        company.append(result.find_element_by_class_name("company").text)
#        print(school)

        try:
            salaries.append(result.find_element_by_class_name("salary").text)
#            print(salary)
        except:
            salaries.append('NA')
            pass
            print("--------")
    # move to next page
    next_page = result.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='pn']")[-1]
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page)
val = smallest(len(titles),len(company),len(salaries))
print(smallest(len(titles),len(company),len(salaries)))

for i in range(0,val-1):
    resultlist.append(titles[i])
    resultlist.append(company[i])
    resultlist.append(salaries[i]) 
    wr.writerow(resultlist) 
    resultlist = [] 
Resultfile.close() 
final_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Title': titles,
     'School': company,
     'Salary': salaries
    })

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[schema]', echo = False)
final_df.to_sql(name = 'my_table', con = engine, if_exists = 'append', index = False)    

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Yes thankyou I also need to dump into DB at the same time @Prakhar

Comment: ok what db are you using. Also do you need to create table or is it already created.

Comment: Mysql no not created

Comment: Hi @stack sure web scraping is just a skill that requires practice like any other you can try out different websites as per your understanding and test if it works. Also looking at few stackoverflow questions with webscraping tag might come in handy.. If you still require some assistance do post  doubts. Happy Learning!! :)

Comment: Also If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left hand side in my answer. And feel free to upvote the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209075/discussion-between-stack-and-prakhar-jhudele).

Comment: Once see this in your free time https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209075/discussion-between-stack-and-prakhar-jhudele

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built in module for writing to CSVs. The below is an example of two functions; create the CSV file with the headers and write your data to the CSV. If you supply a list of values to the write_to_csv() function it will write the entire list to the CSV, one value for column

```
from csv import writer   

# creates initial CSV with headers
def create_csv(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as f:
        csv_writer = writer(f, delimiter=',')
        headers = ['Title', 'Company', 'Salary']
        csv_writer.writerow(headers)

# appends data to the next row in a CSV file
def write_to_csv(file_name, row):
    with open(file_name, 'a', newline='') as f:
        csv_writer = writer(f, delimiter=',')
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

For the database this would depend on what database you're using, for example SQLite3 which is also comes with Python

```
import sqlite

def write_to_db(data):
    db.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ..... """)
    db.commit
```

At the start of your script you would create the CSV and then when you've collected your data call both functions to write to CSV and to the DB

```
file_name = "My_CSV.csv"
create_csv(file_name)

for result in result_set:
    data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "resultsCol")))
    result_set = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "jobsearch-SerpJobCard")))
for result in result_set:

    to_write = []  # list container for your data

    title = result.find_element_by_class_name("title").text
    to_write.append(title)  # append to list to write

    school = result.find_element_by_class_name("company").text
    to_write.append(school)  # append to list to write

    try:
        salary = result.find_element_by_class_name("salary").text
        to_write.append(salary)  # append to list to write
    except:
        to_write.append("")
        pass
        print("--------")

    # pass the data to the functions to write it out
    write_to_csv(file_name, to_write) 
    write_to_db(to_write)

# move to next page
next_page = result.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='pn']")[-1]
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page)
```

Comment: How the data scraped through my script will be inserted?

Comment: That depends at what point you're inserting it and what you want the result to be. For example in your code you have a comment to move to next page. If you want 1 page's data per row in your CSV then do the inserts just before it moves to the next page

Comment: after for loop should I need to write sorry I didnt understand:(

Comment: I've edited my answer using your code, hopefully it's a bit more clear now

Comment: will it automatically create file with that name or we should create manually?

Comment: The create_csv() function creates the file.You don't really need this unless you definitely want headers in your document

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209066/discussion-between-stack-and-meshi).